# Remove spaces when amending a text file using Python

Tags: python

Good Day,

I am a new here an new to coding so worry if this a silly question.

I need some help! I have the following Python code that amends a line in a text file. However, every time I run it, it adds spaces before each word in the text file. Does anyone know why?

```
with open ("sheepfile.txt",'r') as My_Sheep: 
    data = My_Sheep.readlines() 

with open ("sheepfile.txt",'w') as My_Sheep: # opens the text file as ‘w’
    for I, line in enumerate(data, 1):
        if I == Line_num: 
        My_Sheep.writelines( '%s, %s, %s, %s' % (Update_Sheep)) 
    else: 
        My_Sheep.writelines(line) 

My_Sheep.close() # close the file
```

So the text file as the following original text

```
Matt,1,A,Blue
Katy,34,B,Pink
Isobel,32,C,Yellow
```

But when I run the code and say change age of Matt to 2, I get:

```
Matt,2, A, Blue
Katy,34,B,Pink
Isobel,32,C,Yellow
```

There is now a space before the 'A' and a space before 'Blue'

A further space will appear ever time run the code. Does anyone know how I can get rid of them or stop them from appearing?

Comment: See the spaces in your format string `'%s, %s, %s, %s'`?

Comment: Also please take a look at [pep8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) style guide for coding conventions.

Comment: Khelwood - Thank you so much.